# How can I access the bumper sensors on a turtlebot in a simulation?

Tags: gazebo, roomba, turtlebot, plugin, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been working on a project, and I need to turn a certain direction when a turtlebot bumps into something. I'm looking for a ROS plugin to use in a simulation in Gazebo. I can't seem to find anything in any turtlebot repositories or on the ROS wiki.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222930/how-can-i-access-the-bumper-sensors-on-a-turtlebot-in-a-simulation?/) by [aek](https://answers.ros.org/users/25394/aek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe there is something wrong or broken. I am also having problems to reading bumper events when using kobuki in Gazebo. It's like the kobuki plugin for gazebo is not publishing bumper events.

---

Originally posted by [fmrico](https://answers.ros.org/users/13346/fmrico/) with karma: 85 on 2017-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0